# Proof of the Dunford-Pettis theorem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to know where to find a complete proof of the Dunford-Pettis theorem:
A sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 0} \subset L^1$ is uniformly integrable if and only if it is relatively compact for the weak topology $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$.

Comment: The book of Albiac and Kalton.

Comment: You can also find it in the article by J. Diestel, *Uniform integrability: an introduction*. I believe you can freely access this on the web.

Answer (score 5):

This is surely in many places, but a reasonably complete proof is given in Section III.2, Theorem 15 of

J. Diestel, J. J. Uhl, *Vector measures*. American Mathematical Society 1977.